# Update Node-js in ruby:2.7.1-alpine

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I use ruby:2.7.1-alpine for my project
it installs Node version 12, I need version >=16 (I think 18 is desirable) to work with react.

how can I update the version in my Dockerfile ?

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine


ARG RAILS_ROOT=/task_manager
ARG PACKAGES="vim openssl-dev postgresql-dev build-base curl nodejs-current yarn less tzdata git postgresql-client bash screen gcompat"

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk add --update --no-cache $PACKAGES

RUN gem install bundler:2.1.4

RUN mkdir $RAILS_ROOT
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock  ./
RUN bundle install --jobs 5

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

ADD . $RAILS_ROOT
ENV PATH=$RAILS_ROOT/bin:${PATH}

EXPOSE 3000
CMD bundle exec rails s -b '0.0.0.0' -p 3000
```

currently in this build the following options are available:

```
bash-5.0#  apk search nodejs
nodejs-12.22.12-r0
npm-12.22.12-r0
nodejs-current-doc-14.5.0-r0
nodejs-current-14.5.0-r0
nodejs-dev-12.22.12-r0
nodejs-current-dev-14.5.0-r0
nodejs-doc-12.22.12-r0
```

I can't figure it out.

Comment: If it's a Ruby application, how and why does it need Node?  Can you build a front-end application in a separate build stage, `FROM node:20 AS frontend`?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not comfortable with that option(

Answer (score 0):

I change

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine
```

to

```
FROM ruby:3.0-alpine
```

and build a new image

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options to be somewhat independent of your original image:

- Use [node version management](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) this tool helps keep multiplie\manage installation of node in the system. There are some caveats using it with alpine but it is solvable. Check out their documentation.
- Second option (less pretty in my opinion) is to use *copy from* another pre-build node alpine image, it can be done like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.7.1-alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade

# copying node binaries, and yarn stuff
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/node
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
COPY --from=node:18-alpine /opt/yarn-v1.22.19 /opt/yarn-v1.22.19

# create proper symlinks
RUN \
    ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/corepack/dist/corepack.js /usr/local/bin/corepack \
    && ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npm \
    && ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js /usr/local/bin/npx \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarn /usr/local/bin/yarn \
    && ln -s /opt/yarn-v1.22.19/bin/yarnpkg /usr/local/bin/yarnpkg

# here you can you yarn\npm\npx and node
```

To adjust node version, just change *node-XX:alpine* image version, everything should continue to work (except for yarn, you'll have to adjust its path)